# Assign .net control property from a dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, controls

I'm trying to change a control property from a dictionary so basically the key in the dictionary is the property name of that control and the value will be the property value. is there anyway to do this ?

for example in my dictionary I have "Name" as the key and "buttonSave" as the value, how can I relate them to my control to set its property based on the key and value ?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you had a look at possibly using reflection, or a switch statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example for you how to use Reflection in your case with method [PropertyInfo.SetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa330196%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

```
public class Customer
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
}

var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>
                             {
                                 {"Id", new Guid()}, 
                                 {"Name", "Phil"}, 
                                 {"Phone", "12345678"}
                             };

var customer = new Customer();

foreach (var pair in dictionary)
{
     var propertyInfo = typeof(Customer).GetProperty(pair.Key);
     propertyInfo.SetValue(customer, pair.Value, null);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

using System.Reflection;

look up  in MSDN

Answer (score 1):

```
myControl.GetProperty("Name").SetValue(myControl, "buttonSave", null);
```

It would also be good idea to check first that the property exists and that it has a setter.
See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7ykdhsy.aspx) for more information on reflection.